# VS Code expand selection not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have no idea since when it is working like this but when I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> in HTML document the selection will expand to single line and then select whole document without jumping trough every tag. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This native action is not very helpful.

For html and js (may work for some other languages too) there is an extension [Expand region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region).

[image]

Comment: It looks better but still not perfect. Thank you for input